# Trying to run Else statement inside For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I have a small issue with my application that I spotted when testing it. I have a `println` statement that should run to inform the user they have entered an invalid **product code**.

I have a **for-loop** that will run through an Array List of objects where an if statement will match each item in said Array List to a local variable named **searchTerm**.

The issue is that if the **searchTerm** does not match the item[0] with in the ArrayList then, the else statement will run more than once, thus executing the `println` statement multiple times.

```
static void searchProduct() {
     
      System.out.print("Please enter product code to search: ");
      String searchTerm = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
      
          for (int i = 0; i < report.size(); i++) {

              if (report.get(i).code.equals(searchTerm)) { 

                  System.out.println("****************************************************************************"
                                   + "\nPRODUCT SEARCH RESULTS"
                                   + "\n****************************************************************************");

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT CODE >>         " + report.get(i).code); 

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT NAME >>         " + report.get(i).name);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT CATERGORY >>    " + report.get(i).category);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT WARRANTY >>     " + report.get(i).warranty);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT PRICE >>        " + report.get(i).price);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT LEVEL >>        " + report.get(i).stock);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT SUPPLIER >>     " + report.get(i).supplier);

                  System.out.println("****************************************************************************");
              }
              
              else {
                  // System.out.println("The product cannot be located. Invalid Product");
              }    
          } 
      
      System.out.println("Enter (1) to launch menu or any other key to exit");
      String opt2 = in.nextLine();

          if (opt2.equals("1")) {

              mainMenu.Menu();

          }

          else { System.exit(0); }
  }
```

Comment: put `break;` where you want to stop the loop and get out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate out the printing from the looping:

Loop through the list until you find the item:

```
Report r = null;
for (int i = 0; i < report.size(); ++i) {
  if (report.get(i).code.equals(searchTerm)) { 
    r = report.get(i);
    break;
  }
}

// or
for (Report rep : report) {
  if (rep.code.equals(searchTerm)) {
    r = rep;
    break;
  }
}

// or
Report r = report.stream().filter(rep -> rep.code.equals(searchTerm)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Now, `r` is only non-null if you found something, so, after the loop:

```
if (r != null) {
  // Print stuff.
} else {
  // Print message saying you didn't find it.
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Have a lekker day.

Comment: @Brad "lekker" TIL a new word :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean flag to detect if the product is found:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < report.size(); i++) {

              if (report.get(i).code.equals(searchTerm)) { 

                  System.out.println("****************************************************************************"
                                   + "\nPRODUCT SEARCH RESULTS"
                                   + "\n****************************************************************************");

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT CODE >>         " + report.get(i).code); 

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT NAME >>         " + report.get(i).name);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT CATERGORY >>    " + report.get(i).category);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT WARRANTY >>     " + report.get(i).warranty);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT PRICE >>        " + report.get(i).price);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT LEVEL >>        " + report.get(i).stock);

                  System.out.println("PRODUCT SUPPLIER >>     " + report.get(i).supplier);

                  System.out.println("****************************************************************************");
                  found= true;
              }
              
             
          } 
          //end of the loop
          if(!found) System.out.println("The product cannot be located. Invalid Product");
```

Comment: It's better to use an enhanced for loop (`for (Report r : report)`).

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful to know!

Answer (score 0):

Switch the data structure used for searching the items in 'report' from a List to HashMap to avoid having to loop through all of them:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> quickSearchMapping;
quickSearchMapping = new HashMap<>(); 
for(int i=0 ; i<report.size ; i++ ){
    quickSearchMapping.put(report.get(i).code, i);
}

while(TRUE){
    System.out.print("Please enter product code to search: ");
    String searchTerm = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    if quickSearchMapping.containsKey(searchTerm){
        Report the_report = report.get(quickSearchMapping.get(searchTerm));
        //print to user stuff in the_report
        break; //break if you wish to
    } else {
        System.out.println("Code entered didn't match any product.");
    }
}
```